# Не могу добавить opensl в qtcreator на Mint

Tags: linux, c, qtcreator, библиотеки, openssl

Скачал библиотеку, распоковал, скомпилировал, все по нинструкции.
Добавил в PRO файл

```
INCLUDEPATH += I-/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2t/include/openssl
LIBS += /usr/src/openssl-1.0.2t/include/openssl/libcrypto.a -ldl -lpthread
LIBS += /usr/src/openssl-1.0.2t/include/openssl/libssl.a
```

далее все нормально, подключаю .h файлы, он их видит

```
#include</usr/src/openssl-1.0.2t/include/openssl/conf.h>
#include</usr/src/openssl-1.0.2t/include/openssl/sha.h>
#include </usr/src/openssl-1.0.2t/include/openssl/bio.h>
#include </usr/src/openssl-1.0.2t/include/openssl/evp.h>
```

нажимаю собрать и он выдает ошибку /usr/src/openssl-1.0.2t/include/openssl/conf.h:62: ошибка: openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory
 # include 
Нажимаю на ошибку, вижу вот такую картину 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что я сделал неправильно? Как правильно добавить openssl в проект на QTcreator ???

Comment: `INCLUDEPATH += /usr/src/openssl-1.0.2t/include`

Comment: Должно быть как выше в комментарии, и плюс ко всему: `#include <openssl/conf.h>` и тому подобное. Погуглите, что ли...

Comment: @PavelGridin, ничего не изменилось

Comment: @0andriy, необходимые инклуды подключены